# Yearbook - Style "Humans of ~" Typesetting

Tags: graphics, numbering, columns

Salutations, all!
I'm very new to this, so feel free to explain it to me like I'm 5.

I don't even know where to get started. I'm really desperate, and I've seen some heroic things coming out of this forum. Maybe someone browsing has done just that already and can fill me in on the steps to take to get started, and link to places to help me figure out the rest. The bottom two florals can be exported to an image format or preserved as a vector.

I'm working with a large team, and we don't have enough time to train everyone in Inkscape, so what I want out of this is to be able to do something like:

```
{image.tiff}{firstname lastname}{quote}
```

And have it output the rest here. That way we can use github, avoid moving huge tiffs around. I'm sure I can find cover pages as a template to prepend. I think a conditional might be necessary, since I want short enough quotes to be front and centre, but longer quotes to be separated into up to 3 columns.

This is my very first post and I apologise if I'm breaking any etiquette, and please show me the path. Thank you so much for reading, and my eternal gratitude for any help that sets me on the right path.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Many thanks for your polite guidance. I will keep this in mind for all future posts.

Comment: What TeX style did you use to create this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [
    alternative=doublesided,
    location=margin,
    style=bold,
  ]

\setuplayout
  [
    topspace=0pt,
    header=.5\paperheight,
    height=middle,
    footer=2\lineheight,
    bottomspace=2cm,
    %
    backspace=2cm,
    leftmargin=2cm,
    leftmargindistance=0pt,
    width=middle,
    rightmargindistance=0pt,
    rightmargin=2cm,
  ]

\setupexternalfigures
  [
    location={default,local,global},
  ]

\definelayer
  [pageupper]
  [
    x=0mm,
    y=0mm,
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=.5\paperheight,
  ]

\definelayer
  [pagelower]
  [
    x=0mm,
    y=.5\paperheight,
    width=\paperwidth,
    height=.5\paperheight,
    state=repeat,
  ]

%\setlayer
%  [pagelower]
%  {\externalfigure[ornaments][width=\paperwidth,height=.5\paperheight]}

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background={pageupper,pagelower}]

\definehead
  [person]
  [subject]
  [
    alternative=middle,
    page=yes,
  ]

\starttext

\startperson[title={Firstname Lastname}]

  \setlayer
    [pageupper]
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=\paperwidth,height=.5\paperheight]}

  \startnarrow[middle=.25\textwidth][middle]
    \input knuth
  \stopnarrow

\stopperson

\startperson[title={Firstname Lastname}]

  \setlayer
    [pageupper]
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=\paperwidth,height=.5\paperheight]}

  \startmixedcolumns[n=2,balance=yes]
    \input knuth
    \input knuth
  \stopmixedcolumns

\stopperson

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much. This is perfect! I'll add the florals as another picture on the bottom, with the text as an overlay. Thanks for setting me off on the right track!